# How can I get the querystring from a URL before angular starts running?

Tags: angularjs, url, query-string

So I've got an old application that lives at `url.com/app`.  Through most functions of the app, a guid is passed as an ID in the query string `url.com/app?ID=guid`.  I'm working on deprecating that app with a new angular SPA, but my users have bookmarks to the URL with the query string above.  Now that I don't need the querystring in angular (I'll be using routing instead of different pages), how can I on page-load grab the querystring, store it in $rootScope, and move on?

What's happening right now is if I type `newurl.com/app?querystring`, angular will change it to `newurl.com/app?querystring/#`, and $location can no longer see the querystring.  Is there any way I can grab the querystring on page load and store it, and then potentially wipe it out?

Here is my module declaration:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('AngularWebAPI', ['ngRoute', 'common'])
        .run(['$rootScope', '$route', '$location', function ($rootScope, $route, $location) {
            $rootScope.locationSearch = $location.search();
        }]);
})();
```

When I run it at `newurl.com/app?querystring`, it changes it to `newurl.com/app?querystring/#`and `$rootScope.locationSearch` is an empty object.  But if I run it at `newurl.com/app/#/?querystring` `$rootScope.locationSearch` will have the value of that querystring, but that's not the URL my users will have bookmarked.

Comment: maybe look into `html5mode`, it doesn't require the hash

Comment: Ooh, I hadn't heard of that. I'll check it out

Comment: you can set it in your `.config` like so `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Comment: @user2954587 more to it than just setting angular config...also have to set up server config

Comment: @charlietfl Ahh, dang, I don't have access to configure the server.

Comment: that's not good because using mod-rewrite on server is going to help. This can't really be solved in the client only

Comment: Whoops, I was wrong.  I thought you meant I needed to modify IIS but it looks like I could do the configuration in the API.  Here's a link I found: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#user-content-how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode